# Write user input to a file and then read it

Tags: c, file, user-input

I have to recieve user input with this style:

```
U word word2 word3
U word word2 word3
R word
R word
X
```

I want to write it to a file and then read what was written but the program is in a endless loop, and the file is being created but its empty, it seems to me the program never leaves the while loop that writes to a file for some reason.

```
void write_to_file(FILE *fp){
    char buffer[37];
    while(fgets(buffer, 37, stdin)){
        fprintf(fp, "%s", buffer);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

void read_from_file(FILE *fp){
    char buffer[37];
    char tipo;
    char input_a[6];
    char input_b[26];
    while(fgets(buffer, 37, fp)) {
        sscanf(buffer, "%c %s %[^\n]", &tipo, input_a, input_b);
        switch(tipo) {
            case 'U' :
                // do stuff
                break;
            case 'R' :
                // do stuff
                break;
            case 'X' :
                exit(0);
                break;
            default :
                printf("Invalid Operation\n");
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    FILE *fp = fopen("input.txt","a+");
    write_to_file(fp);
    read_from_file(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

I opened the file with `a+` because in case the file already exists i want to write after the last line

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When this loop `while(fgets(buffer, 37, stdin))` fails ?

Comment: @achal that loop should end when there is no more user input, but it doesnt

Comment: Thats what I asked. you need to put some condition to break it. How will you inform to `fgets()` about "there is no more user input" ?

Comment: @achal well 'fgets()' returns null when there isnt anything more to read but even if i do 'fgets(buffer, 37, stdin)!=NULL' the file is still empty for some reason

Comment: Thats if you are reading from some text file as if nothing left in the file  & it reaches `EOF`  it returns NULL. Here your case is different, you are reading from `stdin` stream ?

Comment: @achal yes i am reading the user input from stdin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172297/discussion-between-achal-and-mdordio).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*the program is in a endless loop ?* Its because of below `while()` loop

```
while(fgets(buffer, 37, stdin)) {
}
```

As `man 3 fgets` says

> fgets() return s on success, and NULL on error or when end
>          of file occurs while no characters have been read.

you can end this loop by hitting `ctrl+d` but if you press `ctrl+d` your main process `a.out` gets terminated. One way to solve this problem is give one extra `\n` or `ENTER` as input at last and then chen the return value of `fgets()`.

Here is the sample code

```
void write_to_file(FILE *fp){
        char buffer[37], *ptr = NULL;
        while((ptr = fgets(buffer, 37, stdin))!=NULL) { /* It return NULL upon reaching EOF */
                if(*ptr != '\n') { /* at last user enters \n, compare here, if true , break the loop */
                        fprintf(fp, "%s", buffer);
                }
                else
                        break;
        }
        fclose(fp);
}
```